# Is it possible to disable audit programmatically in Dynamics CRM (2013/2016)?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, audit

Is there an option to globally disable auditing using the CRM service? It can be done via web interface but I need to do it programmatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you should try making a web service call to update the `IsAuditEnabled` field of the Organization record.

[Configure entities and attributes for auditing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334236.aspx)

> You enable or disable auditing at the organization level by setting a
>   particular attribute value of the organization record.

[Organization entity messages and methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309569.aspx)

> An organization represents the top level of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   business hierarchy. The organization can be a specific business,
>   holding company, or corporation. The schema name for this entity is
>   Organization.

[Organization entity attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328408.aspx)

> IsAuditEnabled - Is Auditing Enabled - Boolean - Indicates whether
>   auditing of changes is enabled.

Comment: Thank you - it worked :) I tried it earlier but it turned out that the entity name had to be in lower case ("organization"). For future reference - for some reason UpdateAttributeRequest did not work and I had to do it via UpdateRequest on the Organization entity.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is only possible to retrieve audit data info from the SDK, and delete partitions, only, based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328218.aspx)